# Fire (Mantaflow) showing in render viewport, but rendering some frames blank

Tags: rendering, fire, mantaflow

Hi there fellow Blenders,

I have stumbled on an odd issue; I have been playing around with a fire animation for a bit now, and am happy with the bake and the final look. I have rendered a test in Eevee to verify that the animation looks about right, and now I want to do the final render in cycles. It does indeed look very nice (IMO haha), but only in some frames, because just shy of half of them come out blank for some reason I can not currently grasp.

I am aware of all the usual starting issues with renders missing textures etc, and that is not what is causing this. The really weird thing is that the fire and smoke renders in the render view in viewport, but when rendering the same frame to an image file, it comes out blank? Other frames come out fine, but somewhere around 40% of them render nothing but greyness

Attaching screenshot here, I can attach the file later if needed, but the issue should be pretty clear from this screenshot alone I think.

[image]

I have 2 sampling substeps for the inflow, fuel of 1.5 and an initial velocity of 1 m/s, which are the only settings I changed that I can think, but I don't see these settings causing anything remotely like this issue. As you can see, the scene is very simple, so I am finding this rather confusing. I have searched everywhere I could think of for answers, but only finding the usual newbie issues I have already solved in my early time "playing with fire" Have any of you come across this particular issue before?

Comment: I have solved it for now, by simply removing the domain, adding it back in, and baking again. As far as I can tell, all settings are the same, and it works fine now.
I do however not like to not understand why something doesn't work as expected, so I will leave the question open in the hopes that someone can shed some light on it.